# Capybara Tests: can't log in user using warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I use **capybara 2.3.0**; **selenium 2.42.0**; **ruby 2.1.0**; **rails 4.1.0**; **rspec 3.0**

Tried to use the following method:

```
include Warden::Test::Helpers 
describe "Log in" do
  it "creates user and log it in" do
    visit '/' 
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user 
    login_as user, scope: :user 
    user 
  end 
end
```

But nothing happened, user isn't logged in. Please, suggest what to do?